# Reimage Computer with Windows

Tags: windows, hard-drive, disk-image, reinstall

I have an Intel NUC (NUC7i5BNB) that I originally imaged with Ubuntu. I then added Windows and so the grub boot manager added Windows to the boot options.

I haven't used the Ubuntu option in years, and even when I did, I rarely used it. So, I was wanting to reorder by boot options so that Windows is first. I did accomplish this...

However, I want to get rid of Ubuntu completely (for a variety of reasons). My machine has two disks, Disk 0 and Disk 1. Here is a picture:

[Picture of disks and partitions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx2i6.png)

Disk 0 is where I store all my personal files. Disk 1, along with the system stuff, is where the Ubuntu and Windows 10 OSs currently reside.

My question is: is there a way to reimage Disk 1 (with the operating systems) to Windows without touching Disk 0 at all (which has my personal data) and once Disk 1 is reimaged I can "reconnect" to Disk 0?

Comment: Note that *any* change to the file system has risks, so first **make full drive images** of all drives. If something goes wrong, you have a fallback, and the images may also help in moving the Recovery partition, if you wish to keep it. You'll also want to eliminate booting through grub, which would still point to a non-existent Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the Linux boot entry from the EFI partition will let you
boot directly to Windows and then remove the Linux partition.

This procedure is taken from the post
[Uninstall GRUB and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader)
and I quote from the
[answer by armadadrive](https://askubuntu.com/a/869888/963426):

> 1. Run a `cmd.exe` process with administrator privileges
> 2. Run `diskpart`
> 3. Type: `list disk` then `sel disk X` where X is the drive your boot files reside on
> 4. Type `list vol` to see all partitions (volumes) on the disk (the EFI volume will be formatted in FAT, others will be NTFS)
> 5. Select the EFI volume by typing: `sel vol Y` where Y is the `SYSTEM` volume (this is almost always the EFI partition)
> 6. For convenience, assign a drive letter by typing: `assign letter=Z:` where Z is a free (unused) drive letter
> 7. Type `exit` to leave disk part
> 8. While still in the `cmd` prompt, type: `Z:` and hit enter, where Z was the drive letter you just created.
> 9. Type `dir` to list directories on this mounted EFI partition
> 10. If you are in the right place, you should see a directory called `EFI`
> 11. Type `cd EFI` and then `dir` to list the child directories inside `EFI`
> 12. Type `rmdir /S ubuntu` to delete the ubuntu boot directory
>
> Assuming you only ever had two operating systems (Win 10 & Ubuntu) you
> should now be able to boot directly to Windows without hitting the
> black grub screen.

You may now delete the Linux partition, which I assume is the 77.46 GB
partition that has no drive-letter.

Before doing all this, I suggest creating a good backup of your data,
and perhaps also a disk image backup of the whole disk,
in case of a serious problem.

Comment: Thanks, @harrymc. Do you reckon this will still work even if I do not currently see Windows Boot Manager in the UEFI settings? I initially tried this: https://itsfoss.com/uninstall-ubuntu-linux-windows-dual-boot/ but did not see Windows Boot Manager.
Currently, I am backing up all the files on D:, but not a disk image of Disk 1 (or Disk 0, just the files themselves) as I do not really care about the data on Disk 1 (the operating systems).

Comment: Regarding whether it will work, I am thinking about doing what you suggested in conjunction with the recommendations here: https://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/how-to-uninstall-ubuntu-in-a-windows-10-dual-boot-system/#:~:text=1%20How%20to%20Uninstall%20Ubuntu%20in%20a%20Windows,Restart.%204%20Overwrite%20the%20Linux%20Boot%20Loader%20.

Specifically the command: bcdedit /set “{bootmgr}” path \efi\microsoft\boot\bootmgfw.efi

Comment: I'm a bit confused : How can you boot to Windows if you don't see in the EFI partition the folder ` \microsoft` (or similar)? If you don't care about the installed operating systems and have technical problems with my answer or these articles that you found, a strong-arm method would be to install Windows from USB while formatting the disk.

Comment: I followed the instructions here, unfortunately I could not get it to boot into Windows thereafter (I probably lack the technical expertise). I attempted a variety of actions to access the existing windows installation, including bcdboot, etc. (a variety of errors appeared, I think the underlying problem was that my windows disk did not have "write" permissions...?). Anyways, I ended up reimaging the machine with Windows. Several resources were helpful (see next comment).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-installing-using-the-mbr-or-gpt-partition-style?view=windows-11

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/fresh-usb-windows-10-install-failing/2282930a-7328-4cbc-9265-0dd01b5a9996